# big.matrix as data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking, ehcache-bigmemory, r-bigmemory

I've recently started using R for data analysis. Now I've got a problem in ranking a big query dataset (~1 GB in ASCII mode, over my laptop's 4GB RAM in binary mode). Using `bigmemory::big.matrix` for this dataset is a nice solution, but providing such a matrix 'm' in the `gbm()` or `randomForest()` algorithms causes the error:

```
cannot coerce class 'structure("big.matrix", package = "bigmemory")' into a data.frame
```

class(m) outputs the folowing:

```
[1] "big.matrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "bigmemory"
```

Is there a way to correctly pass a `big.matrix` instance into these algorithms?

Comment: if other solutions fail, you might want to give Revolutions a try. I don't know if it supports `randomForest` or not but I think they have support for large memory necessities. See, for example, `http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/products/enterprise-big-data.php`. Note that it is proprietary software. There is a free academic version.

Comment: Can you provide the actual `gbm` and `randomForest` calls you're using? Specifically, are you using the formula interface for `randomForest`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I obviously can't test this using data of your scale, but I can reproduce your errors by using the formula interface of each function:

```
require(bigmemory)
m <- matrix(sample(0:1,5000,replace = TRUE),1000,5)
colnames(m) <- paste("V",1:5,sep = "")

bm <- as.big.matrix(m,type = "integer")

require(gbm)
require(randomForest)

#Throws error you describe
rs <- randomForest(V1~.,data = bm)
#Runs without error (with a warning about the response only having two values)
rs <- randomForest(x = bm[,-1],y = bm[,1])

#Throws error you describe
rs <- gbm(V1~.,data = bm)
#Runs without error
rs <- gbm.fit(x = bm[,-1],y = bm[,1])
```

Not using the formula interface for `randomForest` is fairly common advice for large data sets; it can be quite inefficient. If you read `?gbm`, you'll see a similar recommendation steering you towards `gbm.fit` for large data as well.

Comment: Can I convert a `data.frame` to `big.matrix` using `as.big.matrix`? Because when I convert I cannot access the elements of the converted 'big.matrix' as in: `> cp2006.big.matrix<-as.big.matrix(cp.2006)
Warning message:
In as.big.matrix(cp.2006) :
  Coercing data.frame to matrix via factor level numberings.
> class(cp.2006)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(cp2006.big.matrix)
[1] "big.matrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "bigmemory"
> cp2006.big.matrix
An object of class "big.matrix"
Slot "address":
<pointer: 0x7fceb865caa0>`

Answer (score 2):

It is often the case that the memory occupied by numeric objects is more than the disk space. Each "double" element in a vector or matrix takes 8 bytes. When you coerce an object to a data.frame, it may need to be copied in RAM. You should avoid trying to use functions and data structures that are outside those supported by the bigmemory/big*** suite of packages. "biglm" is available, but I doubt that you can expect gbm() or randomForest() to recognize and use the facilities in the "big"-family.